# Fix iOS ipa file (missing code-signing certificate)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, application-loader

I'm able to compile and deploy my iPad app to my iPad device with no problems. But when I use Apple's Application Loader program to submit the ipa to iTunes Connect, I always get this error:

`Invalid Provisioning Profile` and `Missing code-signing certificate`.

Is there any way with xcode or some command-line tool to "fix" my ipa, or re-sign it with my provisioning profile? The ipa is generated from a 3rd-party app (not Apple), and the result is this ipa file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of blogs and articles that describe the re-codesigning of apps

Sometimes Apple's App Loader is actually complaining about a mismatch of the entitlements inside the profile - so make sure those are correct as well.

I highly recommend this article from Objc.io http://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/inside-code-signing/

Looks like some folks have built some GUI's for doing the same thing.

http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/